# How to speedup the xts data conversion to DatatimeVector in Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, xts, rcpp

I am using Rcpp  for analysis of XTS data and get its time index by using the following rcpp code:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace std;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
DatetimeVector xtsIndex(NumericMatrix X)
{
  DatetimeVector v(NumericVector(X.attr("index")));
  return v;
}

DatetimeVector tmpindexDaily = xtsIndex(askDailymat);  // Get xts index to Rcpp vector
```

It turns out this conversion takes 2 ms to execute on a certain set of data were I only need time index, without this code, it takes less that 100 microseconds.
Is there any way to better optimize the conversion or to avoid it entirely.

Comment: Can you add `dput(askDailyMat)` to your question please?

Comment: @nrussell did you mean to call dput() r function in Rcpp code? I think it will slow down the calculation if calling any R function. I got the original codes from Dirk Eddelbuettel's post at http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/getting-attributes-for-xts-example/

Comment: No, I just needed an example object to test your function on. Thank you. What's going on with this freestanding line: `DatetimeVector tmpindexDaily = xtsIndex(askDailymat);` - is that part of a larger piece of code, or just something you included accidentally?

Comment: @nrussell The line DatetimeVector tmpindexDaily = xtsIndex(askDailymat) is used to call this xtsIndex function, it is the part of a larger piece of code, and the input askDailymat is xts data type, which is like this (time index and price level): 2010-01-04 00:02:20   -1044.0
2010-01-04 00:02:21   -1045.0
2010-01-04 00:02:26   -1045.0
2010-01-04 00:18:16   -1047.5
2010-01-04 00:42:52   -1047.5
2010-01-04 01:07:25   -1046.5
2010-01-04 01:25:03   -1047.5
2010-01-04 01:25:09   -1046.5
2010-01-04 01:54:20   -1047.5
2010-01-04 02:01:28   -1046.5

Comment: I presume you are the same Alvin as the one who asked [this question about Rcpp and the xts interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706386/rcpp-debug-fatal-error-datetime-h-no-such-file-or-directory-xtsapi-h-no-su).  Why do you keep creating new accounts?

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yes, thanks Dirk, for some reason stackoverflow blocks me to post questions and get a new account

Comment: @Alvin I'm not sure there *is* anything to optimize here, aside from using `const Rcpp::NumericMatrix& X` instead of `Rcpp::NumericMatrix X` as your function parameter, which should get you a very slight performance increase. Interestingly, making the conversion `v(NumericVector(X.attr("index"))); ...` was faster than just directly calling `return X.attr("index");` on my machine, which I am a little curious about.

Comment: @nrussell Thanks for the note, and I just tried yours, which did get a slight performance increase. I was thinking to quote askDailymat as a matrix and using ---- #include <Rcpp/Datetime.h>    std::vector<Datetime> indexDaily =  Rcpp::as< std::vector<Datetime> > (askDailymat), which doesn't work...

Comment: Rcpp's DatetimeVector class is somewhat of an outlier in the Rcpp api. It has never been correctly designed. The way the class is currently organized leads to many many data copies.

Comment: The reason I pull out the time index info is that I try to get the trading time distribution.  A feasible way to speedup is to only convert the xts data rows when there are trading signals since the main reason slows down the  `DatetimeVector tmpindexDaily = xtsIndex(askDailymat)` is because `NumericMatrix askDailymat` that stores xts data is large.  I try to create a submatrix `NumericMatrix tmp = askDailymat(Range(kk,kk), Range(0,1))` to contain the traded xts data kk row, but the time index info is lost. So is there any way to pull out part of `askDailymat` and remain the xts type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be better off just using a `NumericVector` with a proper class attribute.  Here is a quick one-off function I used a few weeks ago [in another project](https://github.com/eddelbuettel/Rblpapi/blob/master/src/blpapi_utils.cpp#L403-L409):

```
Rcpp::NumericVector createPOSIXtVector(const std::vector<double> & ticks, 
                                       const std::string tz) {
    Rcpp::NumericVector pt(ticks.begin(), ticks.end());
    pt.attr("class") = Rcpp::CharacterVector::create("POSIXct", "POSIXt");
    pt.attr("tzone") = tz;
    return pt;
}
```

You can start similarly from other containers, matrix colums, vectors, ... that can hold `double` values and use the fact that time (`POSIXct`) time is really a fractional `double` since the epoch.  Here we got a `std::vector<double>` from another API so the conversion is pretty cheap.